# FIlteredList with Custom Objects

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

I have a class named "MyObject" like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private int type;
    private byte[] file;
    private String fileName;
    private String titolo;

     public MyObject(String tit, int t, byte[] b, String name)
     {    
          titolo= tit;
          type = t;
          file = b;
          fileName = name;
     }


     int getType(){
         return type;
     }
     String getfileName(){
         return fileName;
     }
     byte[] getFile(){
         return file;
     }
     String getTitolo(){
         return titolo;
     }
}
```

I have developed how to load the element of the list, now, I want to filter with FilterList. I would like to filter by "titolo" and "fileName". This is the other class where I'm working right now:

```
public class ContentTab extends VBox{
    Label allegati;
    TextField inseriscitesto;
    ListView<MyObject> view;
    ObservableList<MyObject> data;

    public ContentTab(int width){

         setPadding(new Insets(20));
         setSpacing(10);
         allegati = new Label("Allegati alla lezione");
         allegati.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));
          inseriscitesto = new TextField("");
         data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

         view = new ListView<MyObject>(data);

         view.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        setPrefWidth(width);
        getChildren().addAll(allegati,inseriscitesto, view);


    }

    public void loadElement(List<MyObject> element){

        for(int i = 0; i< element.size(); i++)
            data.add(element.get(i));

                   view.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<MyObject>, ListCell<MyObject>>() {

            @Override
            public ListCell<MyObject> call(ListView<MyObject> arg0) {
                return new ListCell<MyObject>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(MyObject item, boolean bln) {
                        super.updateItem(item, bln);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
                            VBox vBox = new VBox(new Text(item.getTitolo()), new Text(item.getfileName()));
                            ImageView placeHolder;

                            if(item.getType() == myMediaType.PDF){
                                placeHolder= new ImageView(new Image("img/pdf.jpg"));
                            placeHolder.setScaleX(0.5);
                            }
                            else
                                placeHolder= new ImageView(new Image("img/video.jpg"));
                            HBox hBox = new HBox(placeHolder, vBox);

                            hBox.setSpacing(10);
                            setGraphic(hBox);
                        }
                    }

                };
            }

        });
    }

    public void FilterElement(List<MyObject> element){

    FilteredList<MyObject> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, s -> true);

    inseriscitesto.textProperty().addListener(obs->{
        String filter = inseriscitesto.getText(); 
        if(filter == null || filter.length() == 0) {
            filteredData.setPredicate(s -> true);
        }
        else {
            filteredData.setPredicate(s -> ((List<MyObject>) s.).contains(filter));
        }
    });


    }
```

So, my question is, How can I filter by a property of MyObject in `FilterElement` method?

Sorry in advance if I was not clear or the code is too much, but i think I put just the necessary to explain the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ListView` items to be a filtered list, and keep a reference to it, changing it's predicate as the text changes:

```
public class ContentTab extends VBox{
    Label allegati;
    TextField inseriscitesto;
    ListView<MyObject> view;

    public ContentTab(int width){

         setPadding(new Insets(20));
         setSpacing(10);
         allegati = new Label("Allegati alla lezione");
         allegati.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));
          inseriscitesto = new TextField("");
         FilteredList<MyObject> filteredData = new FilteredList(FXCollections.observableArrayList(), s -> true);

         view = new ListView<MyObject>(filteredDate);
        inseriscitesto.textProperty().addListener(obs->{
            String filter = inseriscitesto.getText(); 
            if(filter == null || filter.length() == 0) {
                filteredData.setPredicate(s -> true);
            }
            else {
                filteredData.setPredicate(s -> s.getTitolo().contains(filter));
            }
        });

         view.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        setPrefWidth(width);
        getChildren().addAll(allegati,inseriscitesto, view);

    }
```

Also note that your predicate should be a function that takes a `MyObject` and returns `true` if it should be displayed, or `false` if it should be filtered out. I'm guessing you wanted to check if the `Titolo` property contains the filter text, but you may want to change it to another property.